# how to show content in the wordpress recent post?

Tags: wordpress

```
<div class="row">
                <h3>Recent Posts</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row recent-post-style">
                <ul>
                    <?php
                        $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
                        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
                        foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ) {
                            echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
                            echo the_content('10');
                        }
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

the element the_content('10') is not display the post content.

Comment: Can you show us the function "the_content"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of the post is part of the `$recent` array.

The key you need is `post_content`, which is the raw content of the post.  If you want it formatting in the same way as `the_content()`, then you'll want to wrap it in `wpautop()`.  If you wish to trim it by words (you seem to be doing `the_content(10)`, you can use `wp_trim_words()`.

Here's your amended code:

```
<div class="row">
    <h3>Recent Posts</h3>
</div>
<div class="row recent-post-style">
    <ul>
        <?php
            $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
            $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
            foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ) {
                echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
                echo wpautop(wp_trim_words($recent["post_content"], 10));
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: with wpautop($recent["post_content"]); shows full content. but, i need only 10 words from the content.

Comment: @Thangadurai, ah, that wasn't part of the original question.  You can simply use `wp_trim_words` for that.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: thanks a lot for that. You saved my ass. Can't upvote this as I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: @Thangadurai, no problem - glad it's all sorted